# NetLogo: how to identify the most extended cluster (patch cluster example)?

Tags: netlogo

I'm working with **Patch Cluster Example** from Model Library and I wish to identify the cluster with the highest number of patches = the most extended one and then turn this cluster red.

I know that I can simply

```
count patches with [pvalue = X]  ; X - whatever plabel of patches in connected cluster
```

to know what is the extent of specific `cluster with [plabel = 1]`, `cluster with [plabel = 2]`, `cluster with [plabel = 3]`... To color it, it is simply:

```
ask patches with [plabel = X] [
    set pcolor red ]
```

**However, can I automatically identify the most extended cluster and get the count of connected patches?**

Thank you for all suggestions,

*
*
*

**Which cluster is the most extended one?**

[image: Which cluster is the most extended one?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily adapt the `find-all-components` procedure from the Giant Component example in the NetLogo Models Library.  For convenience, you will need to add global-variables
`component-size`, `giant-component-size`, and `giant-start-node`,
along with a patch attribute `explored?`.  A quick adaptation
(warning: untested!) would be something like:

```
    globals [component-size giant-component-size giant-start-node]
    patches-own [explored?]

    ;; find connected components and their sizes
    to find-all-components
      set giant-component-size 0
      set giant-start-node nobody
      ask patches [ set explored? false ]
      ;; keep exploring till all turtles get explored
      loop [
        ;; pick a node that has not yet been explored
        let start one-of patches with [ not explored? ]
        if start = nobody [ stop ]
        ;; reset the number of patches found to 0
        set component-size 0
        ;; at this stage, we recolor everything to light gray
        ask start [explore]
        ;; the explore procedure updates the component-size variable.
        ;; so check, have we found a new giant component?
        if component-size > giant-component-size [
          set giant-component-size component-size
          set giant-start-node start
        ]
      ]
    end

    ;; Finds all patches reachable from this node
    to explore ;; node procedure
      if explored? [ stop ]
      set explored? true
      set component-size component-size + 1
      ask neighbors4 with [pcolor = [pcolor] of myself] [
        explore
      ]
    end
```

Comment: thank you @Alan, works great after some modifications and you navigated me on a good way ! ;)