# NetLogo: keep clumps if connected patches of certain size

Tags: r, netlogo

I have a clumpy landscape resulting from a crop simulation. I want to identify the size (number of connected patches of darkgreen) of the clumps and I want to keep them only if they are bigger then 20 connected patches.

[image]

This could be equivalent to "sieve" in R, however I can't figure out how to make it in NetLogo?

Any help and ideas how to accomplish this are highly appreciated !

---

the question is based on previous one:
[NetLogo: how to identify the most extended cluster (patch cluster example)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784719/netlogo-how-to-identify-the-most-extended-cluster-patch-cluster-example)

my code actually not working:

```
to find-clusters
  ; assess the pcolors by timber value

  ask patches with [road_by_harvest? = FALSE] [
    set pcolor 53  ; dark green
    ]
  loop [
    ;; pick a random patch that isn't in a cluster yet
    let seed one-of patches with [cluster = nobody]
    if seed = nobody [
      ;show-clusters
      set plabel-list [pcolor] of patches
      stop ]
     ;; otherwise, make the patch the "leader" of a new cluster
    ;; by assigning itself to its own cluster, then call
    ;; grow-cluster to find the rest of the cluster
    ask seed
    [ set cluster self
      grow-cluster ]
  ]
end

to grow-cluster  ;; patch procedure
  ask neighbors4 with [(cluster = nobody) and
    (pcolor = [pcolor] of myself)]
  [ set cluster [cluster] of myself
    grow-cluster ]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you should do depth-first search and label a cluster to a particular group, for all groups (i.e. while there are no groups left unexplored). After you label them, gather all the groups. and remove clusters such that the group size is less than the threshold. In the below example, I color them white...the dark green ones are the one's that remain.

```
patches-own [cluster-id]
to setup
  clear-all

  let threshold 10
  ask patches [if (random 3) = 1[ set pcolor 53]]
  ask patches [set cluster-id -1]
  label-patches
  let clusters remove-duplicates [cluster-id] of patches
  remove-clusters clusters threshold    
end

;; this will label all clusters
to label-patches
  let num-clusters 0
  while [any? patches with [cluster-id = -1 and pcolor = 53]]
  [
    ask one-of patches with [cluster-id = -1 and pcolor = 53]
    [label-neighbors num-clusters]
    set num-clusters num-clusters + 1
  ]
end

;; this will label the whole cluster that a green patch is connected to
to label-neighbors [a-cluster-id]
  set cluster-id a-cluster-id
  ask neighbors4 with [cluster-id = -1 and pcolor = 53][label-neighbors a-cluster-id]
end

to remove-clusters [ clusters threshold]
  foreach clusters
  [
   if count patches with [cluster-id = ?] < threshold 
   [
     ask patches with [cluster-id = ?] [set pcolor white] 
   ]
  ]
end
```